# Pyramid Surface Area

Tags: surfaces, solid-geometry

Square based pyramid has a side length of $220$ (b) and a height of $105.$ Find the surface area.

I tried by "doing" Pythagorean theorem $110^2+105^2=s$

then i did the equation for surface area (total)
$220^2+2\times s\times 220$ and the answer I got was ~$5$ m off the one in the textbook

How do I solve it?

Comment: Where do you find a right triangle with sides of $220$ and $105$?

Comment: if the side is 220 then midseg should be 110. oops.

Comment: typo. still ~5 m off...

Comment: To the nearest $0.1$, I get $66,910.4\text{ m}^2$.

Comment: check values again. answer should be 115 324 m squared.

Comment: Ah, I wasn’t counting the base. With that it’s $115,310.4\text{ m}^2$. The altitude of each face is approximately $152.0690632575$.

Comment: I just worked backwards from $115324$: it implies that the altitude of each face was taken to be $152.1$, so they rounded to the nearest tenth before calculating the area.

Comment: omg grade 9 math ftw (not). thanks. i also got 115 310.4.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what numeric answer you get, your approach looks correct. The only typo I see is that you should be solving $110^2 + 105^2 = s^2$ to get the "height" $s$ of one of the triangular sides when you flatten it out. (You had $s$ instead of $s^2$ in your post). And then $4(220s/2)$ is indeed the total area of the 4 triangular sides.